# How do I approach rendering text in a fully sprite based game? (ActionScript 3)

Tags: actionscript-3, text, bitmap, sprite

I've created a `Canvas` class which has an Array of multiple instances of `CanvasEntity`. Each of these has a `skin` property which is a reference to a previously created instance of `BitmapData`, representing some graphics that can be used.

The `Canvas` runs through this list each frame to perform a render:

1. `lock()` the canvas
2. Clear the canvas using `fillRect()`.
3. Loop through the aforementioned Array and use `copyPixels()` on each of the instances' skin properties.
4. `unlock()` the canvas.

This is all fine, but now I'm a bit unsure of the best way to approach rendering text in the same fashion.

Do I need to make a sprite sheet with all of my glyphs on it, just like I do for all the frames of any other object? Or is there a simpler way to create a piece of `BitmapData` that will represent these?

Making a sprite sheets seems painful as there would need to be individual objects representing each glyph to be rendered.

So far I have this as a sprite sheet:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an individual object for every character. If you want a low-cost text display, have a single class that extends CanvasEntity and accepts a string in the constructor, copies relevant data from the spritesheet to the skin.

Answer (score 0):

The average game doesn't contain that many text. It's generally not a performance critical part that requires to much optimization. You could just create a normal sprite, add a `TextField` with the text and style you need and copy that graphic to canvas. Maybe chache the text graphics if you need them more often.

If you want some animation (character-by-character-appears-with-annoying-sound-of-typewriter-effect), you probably should go with the sprite sheet. But you can create that dynamically just once, using the same technique. Loop through every possible character of your font, draw it to your sheet.